# Rhel7 atomic docker base image subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, docker, rhel7

I'm trying to test out the RHEL 'minimal' atomic base images. However I can see no way to install packages on them.

If I try 'microdnf update' I get this:

```
bash-4.2# microdnf update
(process:10): librhsm-WARNING **: Found 0 entitlement certificates
(process:10): librhsm-WARNING **: Found 0 entitlement certificates
Nothing to do.
```

Subscription manager doesn't seem to exist:

```
bash-4.2# subscription-manager
bash: subscription-manager: command not found
```

How do i provide subscription to this?

Comment: What package have you tried to install with `microdnf`?

Comment: httpd for testing, but the basic "update" isn't working at all.

Comment: Why do you expect `update` to do anything?

Comment: Any ideas on how to provide host subscription to the container?

Comment: Did you see docs to indicate that is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the atomic container inherits the subscription from the host, as explained in a comment here: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3219221

I've tested running microdnf in the container on a RHEL host without subscriptions attached and I get:

```
(process:5): librhsm-WARNING **: Found 0 entitlement certificates
```

After registering the host and attaching it a valid subscription, the atomic-rhel container does not return the warning anymore.